# How to project an image as a texture in VTK?

Tags: c#, vtk

I have a STL file of a 3D scanned object (roughly planar surface, but ~4 million triangles due to surface texture) which I'd like to project an image onto using VTK.

I found an example which looked promising for projecting textures ([Link](https://examples.vtk.org/site/Cxx/Texture/ProjectedTexture/)), but after following along I only see the camera frustrum lines and the texture isn't visible or changing. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the relevant code:

```
// Load model data
vtkSTLReader reader = vtkSTLReader.New();
reader.SetFileName(@"STL\ScannedPart.stl");
reader.Update();
Faces = reader.GetOutput();

// Get poly info
double[] polyCenter = Faces.GetCenter();
double[] polyBounds = Faces.GetBounds();

// ... Read texture image file
vtkImageReader2 textureFile = vtkImageReader2.New();
textureFile.SetFileName(@"Textures\TextureImage.jpg");
textureFile.Update();

// ... Reset camera
Viewport.ResetCamera();

// ... Set camera to projection point
Viewport.GetActiveCamera().SetPosition(polyCenter[0], polyCenter[1], polyCenter[2] + 300);
Viewport.GetActiveCamera().SetFocalPoint(polyCenter[0], polyCenter[1], polyCenter[2]);
Viewport.GetActiveCamera().Roll(-3);
Viewport.GetActiveCamera().SetClippingRange(250, 320);

// ... Get camera position
double[] cameraPosition = Viewport.GetActiveCamera().GetPosition();

// ... Get camera focal point
double[] cameraFocalPoint = Viewport.GetActiveCamera().GetFocalPoint();

// ... Get camera view up
double[] cameraViewUp = Viewport.GetActiveCamera().GetViewUp();

// ... Get planes
double[] planesArray = new double[24];
IntPtr planesArrayPtr = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(planesArray);
Viewport.GetActiveCamera().GetFrustumPlanes(1.0, planesArrayPtr);

// ... Create texture projection
vtkProjectedTexture projectedTexture = vtkProjectedTexture.New();
projectedTexture.SetAspectRatio(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
projectedTexture.SetPosition(cameraPosition[0], cameraPosition[1], cameraPosition[2]);
projectedTexture.SetFocalPoint(cameraFocalPoint[0], cameraFocalPoint[1], cameraFocalPoint[2]);
projectedTexture.SetUp(cameraViewUp[0], cameraViewUp[1], cameraViewUp[2]);
projectedTexture.SetInput(Faces);
projectedTexture.Update();

// ... Map texture on surface
Faces.GetPointData().SetTCoords(projectedTexture.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetTCoords());
                
// ... Create texture
vtkTexture texture = vtkTexture.New();
texture.SetInput(textureFile.GetOutput());

// ... Set poly texture
vtkPolyDataMapper mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper.New();
mapper.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort());
vtkActor actor = vtkActor.New();
actor.SetMapper(mapper);
actor.SetTexture(texture);

// Add poly actor to the viewport
Viewport.AddActor(actor);

// ... Create frustrum planes
vtkPlanes planes = vtkPlanes.New();
planes.SetFrustumPlanes(planesArrayPtr);

// ... Create frustrum source
vtkFrustumSource frustumSource = vtkFrustumSource.New();
frustumSource.ShowLinesOff();
frustumSource.SetPlanes(planes);
frustumSource.Update();

// ... Frustrum mapper
vtkPolyDataMapper frustrumMapper = vtkPolyDataMapper.New();
frustrumMapper.SetInputConnection(frustumSource.GetOutputPort());

// ... Frustrum actor
vtkActor frustrumActor = vtkActor.New();
frustrumActor.SetMapper(frustrumMapper);
frustrumActor.GetProperty().EdgeVisibilityOn();
frustrumActor.GetProperty().SetColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.0); // Yellow
frustrumActor.GetProperty().SetOpacity(0.5);
frustrumActor.GetProperty().SetRepresentationToWireframe();

// ... Add to viewport
Viewport.AddActor(frustrumActor);

// Reset camera clipping range
Viewport.ResetCameraClippingRange();
```

Here's what the texture image looks like:
[Texture image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP0QM.png)

Here's what I'm getting (I want the texture image to be projected onto the surface that the frustrum encompasses):
[Invalid result. No texture, but frustrum looks ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwvDo.png)

**EDIT (2023 08 20):**

Ok, I found the issue above, which wasn't obvious. Apparently the standard ImageReader doesn't properly load files (not sure what, perhaps missing color channels), but a helper function exists to use a more appropriate, filetype-specific loader. By swapping in the code below for the image reading, I now get a projection of the texture onto the poly:

```
// Projected image can be any file format now (e.g., jpg, png)
string textureFilepath = @"Textures\TextureImage.png";
vtkImageReader2 textureFile = vtkImageReader2Factory.CreateImageReader2(textureFilepath);
textureFile.SetFileName(textureFilepath);
textureFile.Update();

// ... Projection works now
```

But I am still struggling with getting the vtkProjectedTexture to behave as I'd like.

While it's projecting, I don't seem to have control over the scaling to match the area of the frustrum planes. I want it to fit the image to the square area that intersects with the part, but what about non-equal aspect ratios? Is there an easy way to handle the projection differently, such that a square area can be easily selected on the surface (e.g. select the 4 corners) and then have the projection within those bounds, scaled to fit?

Perhaps a way to work-out the camera position from a set of points?

Updated image of what I currently have:[image: Current result]

Note that the edges of the image "bleed", which I don't want. I want the image to stretch to fit, especially if the desired projection area is a long rectangle shape.